# sorting in linear time of an array that every element appears at least n/1000 times

Tags: arrays, sorting, data-structures

Hello given an array with n elements that every element appears in the array at least n/1000 times is there an algorithm to sort the array in O(n) time?

Comment: In general, no. At least, not based on how you worded your question. After all, in an array of 1000 unique string, each string appears exactly n/1000 times. And you can't sort that in O(n).

Answer (score 0):

**No** , In worst or average case.

**Why?**

Because n/1000 doesn't really provide any information about what are elements in an array and still needs to perform operation to sort an array in a regular way.

It doesn't really help in reducing time complexity for worst case.

**Yes** ,In best case.
Here best case would be array size with 1000 i.e n = 1000
Then there will be only one element in an array which results in array is already sorted.(You don't need to perform any operations logically)